# Parse.com SQL style queries and CRUD interface

Tags: parse-platform

I just launched my Parse.com app and I'm very happy. But I could really use a tool that allows running SQL style queries in the data browser. Right now even doing a simple "like" is impossible. If there's a tool that does that -- and also allows for CRUD operations for non-technical staff -- I'd be truly grateful.

Looking around I found [this](https://github.com/icangowithout/parse-cms) but it doesn't compile.

So is there a tool that's tried and true? (I know usually Stack Overflow is not for such questions but the Parse.com tag is serving as the help forum so I'm asking here.)